# Resolving template string interpolation at run-time, not at bundle creation time

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a JavaScript application that is bundled into a client-side application and run in the browser.

An old version of the application used to have a variable assignment like this:

```
const API_ROOT_URL = `http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/`;
```

This would presumably get interpolated in the browser.

However, this code now throws a webpack error on webpack 4.42.0:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/client_config.js:4:32)
    at Module._compile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/webpack.config.js:1:99)
    at Module._compile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
```

It seems that the interpolation is happening at the time the bundle is created, when `window` doesn't exist.

Can I get the intended behavior?

Comment: this error is getting thrown when you're building? or it's getting thrown in the browser? I'm on the same webpack version and it's definitely not the behavior for webpack to try and evaluate at build time. webpack doesn't evaluate anything unless some plugin or loader is doing it. it just bundles. what plugins / loaders are you using? some linter maybe that needs to be informed that the runtime environment is the browser?

Comment: It gets thrown at build time. I expanded the backtrace if it helps. How can I diagnose further?

Comment: I think `const API_ROOT_URL = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? \`http://${window.location.hostname}:8000/\` : null;` would calm Webpack a bit.

Comment: @rgov Even with `typeof` operator?

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar Seemed to work with typeof. I'll test further. Any idea why it is necessary?

Comment: it should not be needed at all. This has to be some loader or plugin... your webpack config plugins and module clauses would be useful

Comment: @rgov Since we're ensuring the variable to be not *undefined*, compiler can't complain. Compilers tend to keep track of variables in the scope and if you use any variable outside of those known / tracked *unconditionally*, then they throw an error. `window` object is not known in Node environment. The top-level variable is `process`. Anyway, since using variable without defining it is an error, we use the variable *conditionally* and without referring to its `value`. `typeof` operator doesn't concern itself with the value of the variable but, its type so, compilers have no issue with that.

Comment: @bryan60 Would it still be true in `Node` environment?

Comment: this would throw a runtime error if it were running in a node environment, but it's not running in a node environment. it's running in a browser.  webpack should just bundle this without issue. I do it all the time, having to put checks in for known environment variables would be ridiculous. I can't imagine having to check for the existence of the window or document everytime I want to use them. would make webpack unusable.

Comment: worth noting that webpack's primary use case is bundling things to run in a browser

Comment: @bryan60 I guess when OP said *JavaScript application that is bundled into a client-side application* what he really meant was ***Browser app bundled into Node application***. Most likely, they have been using the same Webpack installation to compile both JS files. In that case, `globalObject` can be set to `this`. See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject

Also, I would suggest checking this link out to verify the setup: https://medium.com/code-oil/webpack-javascript-bundling-for-both-front-end-and-back-end-b95f1b429810

Comment: Here is package.json if curious. https://github.com/WHOIGit/ndsf-sealog-client/blob/master/package.json There's also a .babelrc and a webpack.config.js.dist (though that doesn't seem to have any relevant settings).

Comment: @rgov You're requiring `client_config.js` into `webpack.config.js`, at that point, webpack itself hasn't been initialized and it's still `Node` environment. I would suggest you split configs that use `window` into a separate file and that file be included or required by your **entry point** as defined in `webpack.config.js`. This way you save yourself trouble of checking the existence of `window`.